# Django building objects filter with GET params

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a page that returns a list of items and since the list if large I have put a little filter form on top of it to let users narrow down their view to exactly they want. They are able to select values from a couple of drop downs or leave them empty. So comes the request:

```
/projects/?group=1&project_phase=
```

with empty project_phase filter

or

```
/projects/?group=1&project_phase=2
```

with defined project filter

the names are exactly the attributes that I'm able to define in .filter().

I'm stuck in terms of putting the filter string together for the filter - is there a generic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```
parameters = {field_name: value for field_name, value in request.GET.items()
              if value and field_name in model._meta.get_all_field_names()}
model.objects.filter(**parameters)
```

As suggested by the comments below, there aer a couple of checks to ignore undesired parameters:

- Empty values
- Field names not defined in the model

This should pass all the parameters in the GET request to the `filter` method as you expect.

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks for your comment. I've edited my answer to remove empty parameters so they are ignored in the `filter` call.

Comment: Also it'd make sense to add some checking, e.g. that parameter in GET can be used in `filter`. Otherwise `filter` will fail giving 500 server error.

Comment: @demalexx Yes, you're right. I've updated my response to ignore all fields not defined in the model. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Arthur At least it works for me. Is there something you are missing?

Comment: @jcollado Sorry, I commented too quickly - I didn't know that well the * and ** "operators" and was surprised.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain filters as well (this is pseudo, but should give you the idea):

```
filter_mapping = dict()
filter_mapping['g'] = 'group'
filter_mapping['project'] = 'project_phase'
# .. etc...

o = Model.objects.all() # No filtering (default)

for k in request.GET.items():
  if k in filter_mapping.keys():
     o.filter(filter_mapping[k]=request.GET.get(k))
```